# ffmpeg trim & combine multiple sections of same video with precise timestamps

Tags: video, mp4, video-editing

I'm trying to retain & concatenate the 1st,3rd & 5th 10second portions of the video(along with the audio) while discarding the 2nd & 4th 10second portions of it.

I referred [this](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10396/how-to-concatenate-clips-from-the-same-video-with-ffmpeg) link to get the basic code & modified it to the following code which works as intended.

```
ffmpeg -i "G:\input.mp4" -filter_complex "
[0:v]trim=duration=10[av];
[0:v]trim=start=20:end=30,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bv];
[0:v]trim=start=40,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[dv];
[0:a]atrim=duration=10[aa];
[0:a]atrim=start=20:end=30,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ba];
[0:a]atrim=start=40,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[da];
[av][bv]concat[cv];
[aa][ba]concat=v=0:a=1[ca];
[cv][dv]concat[outv];
[ca][da]concat=v=0:a=1[outa]
" -map [outv] -map [outa] "G:\output.mp4"
```

However, now I want to have finer control over the trim timestamps & tried the following code which should give me the same result as before

```
ffmpeg -i "G:\input.mp4" -filter_complex "
[0:v]trim=start=00:00:00.000:end=00:00:10.000[av];
[0:v]trim=start=00:00:20.000:end=00:00:30.000,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bv];
[0:v]trim=start=00:00:40.000:end=00:00:50.000,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[dv];
[0:a]atrim=start=00:00:00.000:end=00:00:10.000[aa];
[0:a]atrim=start=00:00:20.000:end=00:00:30.000,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ba];
[0:a]atrim=start=00:00:40.000:end=00:00:50.000,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[da];
[av][bv]concat[cv];
[aa][ba]concat=v=0:a=1[ca];
[cv][dv]concat[outv];
[ca][da]concat=v=0:a=1[outa]
" -map [outv] -map [outa] "G:\output.mp4"
```

The result I am getting is a concatenation of the following 10second portions of the input video in the mentioned order:
1st,1st,2nd,3rd,1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th

Any help on this would be appreciated.
Please let me know if you need additional details.

PS:While trying out the code, remove all line breaks & convert it into a single line code

Answer (score 2):

I got it.

Seems the timestamp should not have leading 00s.
The following code worked for me.

```
ffmpeg -i "G:\input.mp4" -filter_complex "
[0:v]trim=start=00.000:end=10.000[av];
[0:v]trim=start=20.000:end=30.000,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bv];
[0:v]trim=start=40.000:end=50.000,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[dv];
[0:a]atrim=start=00.000:end=10.000[aa];
[0:a]atrim=start=20.000:end=30.000,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ba];
[0:a]atrim=start=40.000:end=50.000,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[da];
[av][bv]concat[cv];
[aa][ba]concat=v=0:a=1[ca];
[cv][dv]concat[outv];
[ca][da]concat=v=0:a=1[outa]
" -map [outv] -map [outa] "G:\output.mp4"
```

I think that removing trailing 00s is the answer, but if anyone can elaborate on this further, it would be appreciated.

Comment: OK, so the whole idea is that the time cannot be specified in HH:MM:SS.ms format. It can only be specified in SS.ms format. For example, a time of 01:01:04.35 should be specified as 3664.35 (3600+60+4.35) because the ':' symbol should not be used in the time value.

Comment: HH:MM:SS.ms format is ok with carefully escaping, check https://superuser.com/questions/1145777/use-ffmpeg-filter-complex-trim-with-time-duration-including-hours-and-minutes